# How to use pv command for executable file?

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I know that I can use pv command for showing progress of the command. for example:

```
for i in {1..200}; do sleep 0.1; echo "$i"; done | pv -ls 200 > output.txt
```

But when I have a file main.c which have the following code:

```
FILE * file;
file = fopen("output.txt", "a");
for(int i=0; i<200; i++){
    fprint(file, "%d\n", i+1);
}
fclose(file);
```

and when I execute this file, I have a.out executable file. So, now I want to use pv command for showing the progress of ./a.out command. Is there is any way to do that??

Comment: `pv` is only for pipelines. Your C code doesn't output anything to `stdout` stream, but rather sends output to file. So there's nothing that could go to a pipeline.  You're basically trying to do two opposite things

Comment: What if I output to stdout stream??

Comment: Sure, then you can use it

Comment: I don't know how to use it when my output is in stdout.. Please help me and give me some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in my comment, the core issue is that your `a.out` writes to a file, not to `stdin` stream, which means `pv` can receive no data. When your program outputs data to `stdin` stream, then it works:

```
$ ./a.out | pv -ls 200 > /dev/null                                 
 201  0:00:00 [2.09M/s] [========================>] 100%            

$ cat main.c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i=0;
    for(i;i<=200;i++)
        fprintf(stdout,"%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, you don't have to use `fprintf()` to write to `stdout`, a simple `printf("%d\n",i);` can be sufficient

Comment: I tried this and it worked for this code. But when I tried the same thing for my original code which contains some computation.. it didn't work. It just shows me 100% after the whole execution completes. It doesn't show me the progress increasing before. what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Well, first of all, the program ends quickly. To see progress the command might need to go slower.  Second what exactly you tried with the original code ?  Please post it to `paste.ubuntu.com` and provide link

Comment: I am using CUDA and this is my code http://paste.ubuntu.com/25080734/

Comment: It takes 3 s to complete 1 iteration of the for loop. So, time is not a problem